# Wired Breakers That Control Nothing

Tags: electrical

I have multiple circuits in both my 'service' and 'sub' panels that have wire connected to them, but don't control anything; they've been off for a week now to no apparent or pursued effect.

As a matter of defining practice of whoever last worked on this panel, know that there are in fact empty spaces (no breakers), but no where are there breakers without connected service.

There a 3-dual pole and 7-single pole breakers in the service panel, and one additional single pole in the sub panel. None are relabeled by any means to suggest at multi-branch use.

The dual pole breakers have neutrals connected which caused me to think that they might be either existing or 'proposed' GFI's or AFI's that were never installed.

All existing AFI's are accounted for, and nothing else is off, so it's not a question of whether they read as tripped, because nothing seems to be shut off downstream anyway.

**If those lines go nowhere, isn't it code, or at least best practice, to disconnect unused circuitry from the service to minimize dangerous 'surprises' during construction or renovation?**

Please don't post back a list of occult or out-of-sight residential loads that others might miss: every line-trace, pump, alarm, detector etc. is accounted for.

For lack of relevant recent experience, I am, it seems, stumped by strange, new or convention of modern practice!

I'll take some pictures with the covers removed and post them. I like to keep them at hand anyway in case I have to refer to them remotely without access to the panel.

Great site by the way! Thanks!

P.S. There are no pig-tails on the dual pole breakers but they might be the new style that has the connection on the bottom and don't require them. I haven't checked yet.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Plain dual breakers can use the white/neutral wire as the second hot on a 240 volt circuit.  The white should have black tape/paint on each end, saying it is a hot.  Wire gauge must be at least minimum size/or bigger for the breaker, 12 gauge for 20 amps/10 gauge for 30 amp breakers.

Comment: Two pole breakers don't have pigtails unless they are ground fault (or arc fault?).

Comment: Is there anything else that is weird or broken?  Receptacle sockets that don't work?  (sometimes 1 of 2 sockets will be inoperative)?  Switches that seem to control nothing?   Does your house have wired CO, fire alarm or radon system and can you confirm those work? (you didn't turn them off by mistake)?

Comment: Are you claiming you have three 2-pole breakers that are wired but don't seem to power any receptacle or appliance?  Clothes dryer? Water heater? 240 V receptacles in garage? What is the current rating on these? And there are eight 1-pole breakers that are wired but don't power anything?

Comment: The age of the house/electric system might help.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying. As the post says, there is no marking to indicate that the neutral is hot,, and I pointed out that my suspicion was that then might be AFI. My question is, as I stated, is it not practice to disconnect unused lines from the service? I'm trying to post a picture but no matter how much I reduce the size and quality of the image, it just keeps telling me that the image is too large. Frustrating.

Comment: Don't call any white wire a neutral. A white wire connected to one hot pole of a 2-pole circuit breaker is not a neutral.

Comment: Yes to all of the above. All appliances and baseboard heaters (inluding the gas furnace and water heater) are accounted for, as are all GFI and AFI's. While I'm at it, so is every outlet, light, the sewage evacuator pump, the smoke and CO2 detectors, etc. as are all external landscaped GFI's. I also have a single receptacle in my furnace that is wired but dead regardless of these breakers being on or off. I thought that maybe there had been an electric furnace and hot water heater that no longer required those breakers, but that brings me back to my question.

Comment: Is it or is it not practise to disconnect wire from service if it is not in use, so that it is not charged?

Comment: They won't be powered if you would just switch off the breaker, but personally I question that the circuits do nothing. I would not disconnect the wires from the breakers without more investigation. Get an electrician in with a signal generator to look for terminations or wires sealed up in walls.

Comment: Are there electrical boxes in the attic with only one cable going in? Are there boxes under the eaves? Could there be wiring in place for several mini-split condensing units?

Comment: The dead wired receptacle on the furnace is a problem, if no breaker controls it, because it means you have a broken wire someplace.  If the breakers do not control anything, then you can always disconnect them.  Can also remove the breakers, but need to have spacers on the panel cover to brock the hole/s.

Comment: If you can get some photos of your panels pref. with the dead fronts off, please [edit] your question to add them.  If you didn't sign up with a username/password or Facebook/Google, use the same system/browser you asked your question on.  AFCI and MWBC wiring are easy to spot, we can confirm.

Comment: @tskeldon -- post your picture to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link to it in the comments here, then we can go form there

Comment: I had six such breakers in my panel.  Took me six years to figure out where they all went but eventually I did. A few were easy.  The last couple were pure luck.

Comment: Is this a large, old house that has been repeatedly remodeled over decades by different people? Where is it located?

Answer (score 3):

To attempt to answer the question, as clarified in a comment, IE is it "practice" to disconnect disused wires from power?

There is no harm in leaving a wire live if properly terminated inside a properly installed junction box.  Great idea to leave the breaker switched off but no need to do extra work inside the breaker panel in this case.   Some (like me) might say it's better to have the wire attached to a turned off breaker than to have it coiled up inside the panel.

It would be good practice to label both ends of it as such and equally good practice to label the breaker panel on the legend and in other documentation.  The fact that such labelling is so often done poorly or not at all doesn't create a requirement to disconnect the wire from the breaker.

In an old house you probably have a mixture of:

- working outlets you just haven't found.  Hidden behind furniture, or one odd outlet in a multi-gang box.  Have you really tested every single individual outlet?
- disused circuits terminated in junction boxes.  Possibly not labeled, possibly not accessible as they should be.
- disused circuits improperly terminated in walls, attics, crawl spaces.  Just nutted off (hopefully) and left sitting on the ground

So yes, some of these should have been disconnected from the breaker.  All of them should have been labelled.

Comment: **if properly terminated inside a properly installed junction box** +1. The 'practice' is to do work that meets code, which does *not disallow* unused energized wires.

Comment: Hi everyone! Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your suggestions. I will trace the lines when I get a chance and report back. I own the equipment, I just don't have the time and had hoped to secure a more economical understanding of what seems to be just sloppy practise. This was originally a modest two story home built atop tressel constuction on a steeply sloped lot. It was bought and reworked by a well-know Canadian  architect who transformed it into a westcost contemporary showpiece that was featured in Architectural Digest. Things could be hidden behind newer construction.